# "Some" followed by a personal name

Tags: names

I have heard the expression in the title when referring to a person whose name is the only known piece of information, for example:

> **Some Juan Ferrer** sent me an email last night but I'm hesitant to open it.

I had two questions:

1. Is it correct English, or widely used at least?
2. Where can I find some resources talking about this?

None of my Google searches have yielded any results, so I finally turn to SE community (hoping it is the appropriate site and tags).

Comment: "Some" is a colloquial alternative to "a" (or "an") - like the phrase "Some idiot left the door unlocked".

Comment: Some [one by the name of]...

Comment: In this context, it's a shortened way of saying this: "Someone named Juan Ferrer sent me an email last night. I don't know anybody named Juan Ferrer, so I'm hesitant to open it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Some" is a colloquial alternative to "a" (or "an") - like in the phrase "Some idiot left the door unlocked".

It is normally used when you don't know who that person is, or are pretending not to know, and is an extension of the more general use of "some" to mean "an unknown or unspecified quantity".

http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/some+idiot

"John Doe" is an expression for an unidentified male corpse, so it's usage here as the sender of an email seems odd.

Comment: I used "John Doe" to represent any personal name, like Max Williams. I will change it to Juan Ferrer, just to make it clear. Thanks for the link, though.

Comment: "John Doe" is also used to refer to a hypothetical average man.

Comment: The American, John Doe, is the same fellow as the British Joe Bloggs. But don't tell Interpol.